# I have some error in my Java code while running it

Tags: java, project

[Project link](https://1drv.ms/w/s!An7kEWyTDHfzsRui8rYvBT8Dap2H?e=LWaxWt).

I am trying to complete an assessment task.

I am not sure why my code isn't running. I have given a link of my project.

```
            import java.util.Scanner;
            class MAPCalculator{
             double map;
             double sbp;
              double dbp;


    public MAPCalculator(){
    //no code needed
    }
    public double value(double sbp, double dbp){

    this.sbp=sbp;
    this.dbp=dbp;

    return map;

    }

      public String category(double map){
        //What to do in this function how to sent string 
            String High="High";
        String Low="Low";
         String Normal="Normal";
        return High;
                }
           }
                  class Assignment2{
                public static void main(String[] args){
                double sbp[]= new  double[5];
            double dbp[]= new double[5];
            double map;
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                System.out.print("Enter the Value of SBP(systolic blood pressure) "+(i+1)+"::->>  ");
                sbp[i]=sc.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Enter the Value of DBP(diastolic blood pressure) "+(i+1)+"::->>  ");
                dbp[j]=sc.nextInt();

             map = (sbp[i]+2*dbp[j])/3;

        }

        }
                MAPCalculator obj = new MAPCalculator();
                obj.doublevalue(map);
                System.out.println("The MAP(mean arterial pressure) is::->>"+map+ "mm HG");

    }
}
```

Comment: This will surely be closed. For your next question, please don't spam caps, or yell for help. That is implied in the question. Also, external links to projects are generally a bad idea, instead include a [reprex]. Also review [ask] if you'd actually like an answer. You also *completely neglected to describe your problem* and *ask a specific question*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment2{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        double sbp;
        double dbp;
        double map;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the Value of SBP(systolic blood pressure) ");
        sbp = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the Value of DBP(diastolic blood pressure) ");
        dbp = sc.nextDouble();

        map = (sbp+2*dbp)/3;

        System.out.println("The MAP(mean arterial pressure) is::->>"+map+ "mm HG");

        if (map < 70.0)
            System.out.println(" Your MAP is considered LOW");
        else if (map > 110.0)
            System.out.println(" Your MAP is considered HIGH");
        else 
            System.out.println(" Your MAP is considered NORMAL");


    }

} // end class Assignment2
```

Comment: Thx You Sir For Helping me But How to take data of 5 people using array ?

Comment: do you want to display the results after each entry or do you want to display the results after all 5 people have been entered? If the second, are you supposed to capture their name and include in the output? Some specifics on the problem would help me help you better.

Comment: @DineshUprety I'm confused. You found the answer helpful, but you don't want to mark it as useful?